# Можно ли клик по button, созданной с помощью метода другого класса,обработать с помощью OnClickListener, имплементированного в текущем активити

Tags: android, button, android-button, android-view, android-ui

В классе Metods есть метод, который создает кнопку, добавляет к ней нужные текст,оформление, ширину, высоту, расположение и прочее. Т.к. в разных активити присутствует эта кнопка, которая создается и имеет схожие параметры во всех активити, то я вынесла метод по ее созданию в отдельный класс Metods, и, чтобы ее создать в любом активити, создаю экземпляр класса Metods, и вызываю метод createBackButton();

В текущем активити при определенных обстоятельствах вызывается метод createBackButton();, с помощью которого создается кнопка. Можно ли как-то добавить возможность обработать в текущем активити клик по этой кнопке ?

```
public class Metods {
public void createbackButton (Context context, View view, long startOffSet){
        Button newbutton = new Button(context);
        newbutton.setText(...);
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(...);
        newbutton.setPadding(...);
        newbutton.setTag(...);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newButtonparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        newButtonparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        newButtonparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        newButtonparams.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 10);
        newbutton.setLayoutParams(newButtonparams);
        RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
        rel.addView(newbutton);

        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0,1,0,1,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(1000);
        scaleAnimation.setStartOffset(startOffSet);
        newbutton.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);



    }
}
```

vv

```
public class Step1Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
Metods metods = new Metods();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout....);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.land_1_Imv:
...
 metods.createbackButton(this, land_1_Imv, 2000);
}
}
```

Comment: можно, вы приведите примеры кода создания кнопки и использования в текщем активити, чтобы конкретнее ответить на ваш вопрос

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, дополнила

Comment: newButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) context) - а вообще, по хорошему, завели бы интерфейс с методом getContext() и сделали extends View.OnClickListener. И реализовывали и передавали его

Comment: @ДамирАрманов, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваш `OnClick` добавляем метод, который принимает `tag`, заданный при создании `button`, и по идее должен выполнять обработку в соответствии с меткой:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.land_1_Imv:
                metods.createbackButton(this, land_1_Imv, 2000);

        }
        doAction(v.getTag());
    }
```

А в `Metods` последней строкой в методе `public void createbackButton(Context context, View view, long startOffSet)` добавляем:

```
newbutton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);
```

Comment: В onclick у меня получилось так:  if(v.getTag() !=null && v.getTag().toString().equals("1")){..ну и что-то там происходит.} И еще, можно уточняющий вопрос:  тэг должен быть уникальным в рамках данного активити или всего приложения?

Comment: @VolhaGomel достаточно только в рамках данного активити ,будет достаточно.Но важно понимать, что в отличие от идентификаторов, теги не используются для идентификации видов. Теги - это, по сути, дополнительная информация, которая может быть связана с представлением. Они чаще всего используются в качестве удобного хранилища данных, связанных с представлениями в самих представлениях, а не путем помещения их в отдельную структуру.